# Unresolved assembly reference: UnityEngine Sandcastle

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, documentation, sandcastle

I want to create documentation from visual studio xml comments using Sandcastle Help File Builder.
My project developed with .Net 3.5 and its class library for Unity3d.
When i try to build documentation in Sandcastle all the time Sandcastle return this error :

> MRefBuilder : error : Unresolved assembly reference: UnityEngine (UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null) required by FBCross [C:\Users\Ersin\Desktop\Test\gg\Help\Working\GenerateRefInfo.proj]
>
> SHFB: Error BE0043: Unexpected error detected in last build step.  See
>   output above for details.    at
>   SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.RunProcess(String
>   fileToRun, String args)    at
>   SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.Build()

How can i fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, it doesn't know about UnityEngine. So you need to add that as a reference. The FAQ for Sandcastle [contains a section on this](http://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/1aea789d-b226-4b39-b534-4c97c256fac8.htm#UnresolvedAssembly):

> **Why does my build fail with an Unresolved assembly reference error?**
>   If the build fails in the Generating reflection information
>   step with an error that starts "Error: Unresolved assembly reference",
>   you need to add the named assembly as a reference. This is done by
>   adding a reference to it to the References node in the Project
>   Explorer window.

So locate the UnityEngine.dll and add it as a reference. You should be good to go from there, barring any other missing references.